# How to override 'paint' function of custom delegate class to draw QSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I have added a custom delegator to the `QTableView`. When I double click on an item I see the editor widget which is a 'QSpinBox' and I am able to edit the value fine. This editor widget disappears once the focus is lost and I understand that. What I want is `QSpinBox` to be there all the time. Looking at the Qt example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) I know I need to override the `paint` function of `QAbstractItemDelegate` class to draw the `QSpinBox` but I don't know how to that. In general, I want to know how any of the Qt widgets can be drawn inside a paint function.
For reference, I am having following test code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTableview>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QColor>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QSpinbox>

class SpinBoxDeligate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    QWidget * createEditor(QWidget *parent,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
        const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        auto w = new QSpinBox(parent);
        w->setFrame(false);
        w->setMinimum(0);
        w->setMaximum(100);
        return w;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor)->setValue(index.data(Qt::EditRole).toInt());
    }

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        model->setData(index, static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor)->value(), Qt::EditRole);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
        const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        // What to replace below line with to have a QSpinBox
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model(3, 1);

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        auto text = QString("%0").arg(r);
        QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(text);

        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable
            | Qt::ItemIsEnabled
            | Qt::ItemIsEditable
        );
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
        item->setData(text, Qt::ToolTipRole);
        item->setData(QSize(100, 30), Qt::SizeHintRole);
        item->setData(QIcon(":/QtMVC/Desert.jpg"), Qt::DecorationRole);
        model.setItem(r, 0, item);
    }

    QTableView* table = new QTableView();
    table->setModel(&model);
    table->setItemDelegate(new SpinBoxDeligate());

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout* containerLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    w.setLayout(containerLayout);
    containerLayout->addWidget(table);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for your background problem is to use `paint()` and for that you could create a QSpinBox and use grab to take an image, but before that you should calculate the geometry so that it does not cover the QCheckBox, as you see it is a tedious job, another way is using QStyle but it is still much more code.

A simple solution is to keep the editor open with the [`openPersistentEditor()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) method.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model(3, 1);
    QTableView* table = new QTableView();
    table->setModel(&model);

    table->setItemDelegate(new SpinBoxDeligate());

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        auto text = QString("%0").arg(r);
        QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(text);

        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable
            | Qt::ItemIsEnabled
            | Qt::ItemIsEditable
        );
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
        item->setData(text, Qt::ToolTipRole);
        item->setData(QSize(100, 30), Qt::SizeHintRole);
        item->setData(QIcon(":/QtMVC/Desert.jpg"), Qt::DecorationRole);

        model.setItem(r, 0, item);
        table->openPersistentEditor(model.indexFromItem(item));
    }

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout* containerLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    w.setLayout(containerLayout);
    containerLayout->addWidget(table);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the simple solution, I did not know about it. If possible could you please share the solution related to `QStyle`, you were mentioning. I am very much interested to know how a widget can be drawn using `QStyle`.  Once again thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Sajal 
I have had difficulties in implementing this, first of all by the QCheckBox, I do not know how to calculate its size, and on the other hand I believe that its implementation means monitoring elements that implementing it for me involves unnecessary effort.

Comment: No problem, I understand. I was just wondering would it be simpler to draw `QSpinBox` ignoring checkbox, assuming we have all the item space available to draw just the `QSpinBox`.

Comment: Even so, you will have to implement these methods: https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp#L904 and https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp#L1582

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. It is possible to insert widgets into table cells. I know this is not what you're trying to do but it can be a better solution for your problem. Check [setIndexWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget).
2. If you really want to render QSpinBox, you should use the [render](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) method of QWidget. To try, in your `paint` method create a `QSpinBox` and call it's render method passing it the `QPainter` pointer. After you get it working this way, you can improve your design by possibly holding a 'template' `QSpinBox` instance in your QTableView and use it to render different `QSpinBox` values inside cells where required